# Load insecure content through secure AWS Elastic Beanstalk reverse-proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, reverse-proxy

So I'm trying to load content (images/video) with insecure (http) external sources on my secure (https) site through a reverse-proxy. Otherwise their browser gives them a notification that insecure content is being loaded.

I'm using an AWS Elastic Beanstalk configuration with tomcat and linux EC2 servers.

I was looking at this thread as a starting point, but the solution here requires knowing the domain of the content source. I don't know this since it's user-generated.
https://serverfault.com/questions/744815/nginx-proxy-image-javascript-hosted-externally

I'd appreciate any ideas on how this can be solved!